# Webgl FTP error

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, unity-game-engine, ftp

Im having problems with a webgl build for unity that uses a ftp connection to store and load .xml files. Everything works fine in the editor and on a local ftp server (using Xlight). But when I build a webgl solution and try to save a .xml file I get the following error:

```
> Uncaught abort() at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:875:12)
    at stackTrace (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:889:21)
    at abort (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:3830852:24)
    at _pthread_create (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:13183:2)
    at __ZN6il2cpp2os10ThreadImpl3RunEPFvPvES2_ [il2cpp::os::ThreadImpl::Run(undefined?F?*, void, void*)] (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:3596270:50)
    at Array.__ZN6il2cpp2os6Thread3RunEPFvPvES2_ [il2cpp::os::Thread::Run(undefined?F?*, void, void*)] (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:3746555:7)
    at Object.dynCall_iiii (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:3807075:39)
    at invoke_iiii (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:16008:32)
    at Array.__ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System9Threading6Thread15Thread_internalEP12Il2CppThreadP14Il2CppDelegate [il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Threading::Thread::Thread_internal(Il2CppDelegate?**)] (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:2708698:6)
    at Object.dynCall_iii (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:3813716:38)
```

I have absolutley no idea what this means or how to remotely fix this. My interests in server techs wasn't really at an all time high so some help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

This is my xml upload code I'm currently using:

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost/construct.xml");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "password");

    string xml = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
```

If there is anything else I've left out than please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could be wrong but AFAIK you can't use WebRequest in an HTML5 exported game from Unity.

Comment: Shouldn't be it impossible then to use it in the editor when switched to the webgl platform? It worked perfectly there. But when I use a unity web player platform and test it in the editor it gives error messages and refuses to build to web player because it doesn't recognize webrequestmethods.ftp (it is disabled for web player).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use WebRequest with Unity HTML5 exported projects, since WebRequest relies on threads. Unity's export to HTML5 option does not support threads (yet). The key part of the stack trace is this:

```
at _pthread_create (http://localhost:8080/Development/WebGL.js:13183:2)
```

None of the pthread API methods are implemented by emscripten. At some point in the future we may have thread support in JavaScript from various browsers, but it is not available now.

Note that this does work in the editor, even with the WebGL platform selected, because Unity is not limiting the .NET profile for the WebGL platform as it does for the Web player. We're looking at using profiles to provide earlier error information for platforms like WebGL, but we haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I have to find some other way then.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is a restriction of the WebGL platform now.

Comment: Sorry for the rant but WebGL is not a platform. Browsers/HTML5 is a platform. WebGL is an API. Why does Unity seem to make this so confusing for users. Like Unity's originally naming "UnityScript" as JavaScript has caused no end of confusion. Similarly calling this a "WebGL platform" or the "WebGL" target instead of the "HTML" or Browser some thing more appropriate will again cause no end of confusion for users